# Is there a way I can pause/resume a PHPUnit+Selenium test while I solve the CAPTCHA?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

So i am writing a test script for some forms which uses a CAPTCHA to try and stop bots. obviously no point spending hours is not years trying to develop a way to defeat CAPTCHA using PHPUnit+Selenium but i still want to build the test to continue after the page has been submitted.

I figured that since i have multiple screens the best way i could do this is to run the test in one screen and use something like `executeScript('alert("CAPTCHA time!")');` or some jQuery to let me know when to solve the CAPTCHA myself while the test runs

however i can't see how i can do this, one idea i thought was to have the test stop but the code i current use

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
$this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);

// adding cookie
$this->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$this->driver->manage()->addCookie(array(
  'name' => 'cookie_name',
  'value' => 'cookie_value',
));
$this->cookies = $this->driver->manage()->getCookies();
```

will just start up a new firefox browser rather than continue with the one that was already opened.

the other idea i had was to have the test "pause" until i solve the CAPTCHA and then restart when i am done, but i've no idea how to do this either. and i don't really have a good syntax reference guide for the Webdriver i am using aside from reading though all the code trying to find one function

So is there a way I can pause/resume a PHPUnit+Selenium test while I solve the CAPTCHA?

NOTE: the webdriver i am using is [the Facebook one](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) and i include this `__init__.php` file

```
<?php
// Copyright 2004-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// interface
require_once('WebDriverSearchContext.php');
require_once('WebDriver.php');
require_once('WebDriverElement.php');
require_once('WebDriverCommandExecutor.php');
require_once('WebDriverAction.php');
require_once('WebDriverEventListener.php');

// abstract class
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverKeysRelatedAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverSingleKeyAction.php');

// class
require_once('WebDriverAlert.php');
require_once('WebDriverBy.php');
require_once('WebDriverDimension.php');
require_once('WebDriverExceptions.php');
require_once('WebDriverExpectedCondition.php');
require_once('WebDriverHasInputDevices.php');
require_once('WebDriverKeys.php');
require_once('WebDriverNavigation.php');
require_once('WebDriverMouse.php');
require_once('WebDriverKeyboard.php');
require_once('WebDriverOptions.php');
require_once('WebDriverPoint.php');
require_once('WebDriverSelect.php');
require_once('WebDriverTargetLocator.php');
require_once('WebDriverTimeouts.php');
require_once('WebDriverWait.php');
require_once('WebDriverWindow.php');
require_once('interactions/WebDriverActions.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverMouseAction.php');
require_once('interactions/WebDriverCompositeAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverButtonReleaseAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverClickAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverClickAndHoldAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverContextClickAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverCoordinates.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverDoubleClickAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverMouseMoveAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverMoveToOffsetAction.php');
require_once('internal/WebDriverLocatable.php');
require_once('remote/RemoteMouse.php');
require_once('remote/RemoteKeyboard.php');
require_once('remote/RemoteWebDriver.php');
require_once('remote/RemoteWebElement.php');
require_once('remote/WebDriverBrowserType.php');
require_once('remote/WebDriverCapabilityType.php');
require_once('remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverSendKeysAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverKeyDownAction.php');
require_once('interactions/internal/WebDriverKeyUpAction.php');

require_once('support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.php');
require_once('support/events/EventFiringWebDriverNavigation.php');
require_once('WebDriverDispatcher.php');
require_once('support/events/EventFiringWebElement.php');

// touch
require_once('interactions/WebDriverTouchScreen.php');
require_once('remote/RemoteTouchScreen.php');
require_once('interactions/WebDriverTouchActions.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverTouchAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverDoubleTapAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverDownAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverFlickAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverFlickFromElementAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverLongPressAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverMoveAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverScrollAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverScrollFromElementAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverTapAction.php');
require_once('interactions/touch/WebDriverUpAction.php');
```

though i suspect the files i am using a out of date in comparison to what is on github (really need to upgrade at some point)

NOTE2: i have suggested we turn off the CAPTCHA for debugging but the powers that be have said no and this code existed beforehand so they must have their reasons why we can't just turn it off

Comment: I would try to avoid captcha by running the app/framework in "dev" mode (where auth or captcha is not required), or whitelist local IPs, or configure to use [test API keys](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq?hl=en) on the test environment

Comment: @NoChecksum unless this "dev" mode is something in-built into CAPTCHA then it more or less what i already explained in NOTE2 but i'll inquire as to the other options your suggested. in the off chance that i am stuck with CAPTCHA i would still seek an answer but also for any other rare situation where there is an anti-bot measure i can't turn off or bypass easily

Comment: It's always a good idea to leave the solution finding to the powers that keep you from doing the obvious: Either disable the captcha during test runs, or predefine it and enter the known text (i.e. in dev mode it is always "development mode" as a text, and the test can enter that as the answer).

Comment: you don't want to solve the captcha automatically ?

Comment: @L.Bar it's not possible (to my knowledge). it's one of those one which have you click on a box to prove your human and at random times (at least i assume it's random given i don't always get it) will ask you to select the matching images (ie. select all cakes, select all palm trees). i would if i could but if i could automate the solving of production environment CAPTCHA then i kinda defeat the reason for it's existence

Comment: please try : http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login
if you will need more support i will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running PHPUnit and Selenium though the command line you can use the STDIN Example found on PHP.net's [Input/output streams page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

```
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

when the code reaches that lime everything will pause and wait until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so if you use code like this

```
echo "\nCommand: ";
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "\nInput = '".$line ."'";
```

you can then get text entered into the command line that you can then use selenium to input that into the CAPTCHA form.

the only problem is that if you let Selenium idle too long the session till time out and thus cause errors when the code resumes (and currently looking to try and get around this)