# Pause/Wait Laravel Test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5

I am doing a Laravel 5.4 test and I need to do something manually (activating an e-mail code) before another test to come up. Here's my sample algorithm.

1. I'll send an e-mail for activation.
2. Test if the e-mail was sent.
3. Wait 'till I activate the email.
4. Check if the e-mail is activated.

In this example I need to wait 'til I activate the e-mail code.

Is there a way to pause/sleep/wait on the Laravel test? There's no `sleep()`, `wait()`, `readline()`, or `pause()` function in Laravel test.

P.S. Pls focus on the `wait` query and not on e-mail (this is just an example).

Comment: I think it would be better to only check if the email was sent, save the token, and sent a request to activate the email so you don't have to wait.

Comment: I need the manual intervention with the e-mail (in my example).

Comment: Okay, then the easiest was is to call `sleep(300)` so you have 5 Minutes to continue your tests. maybe this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621029/is-there-a-way-i-can-pause-resume-a-phpunitselenium-test-while-i-solve-the-capt

Comment: Can you generate specific url for local email testing? i have some ideas.

Comment: What do you mean with a specific URL? An activation link?

Comment: pls do not focus on e-mail. focus on pausing.

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel I need to connect to an external site to activate and cannto be done locally.

Comment: What I use for the mean time is the `sleep()` function.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you want to do lots of things in one function. in test principle you should divide your functionality in separate tests and check all of theme one by one . for example you should have a test function to check if your email sent or not then have a test to check if the email receive or not and you have to mock your email and inject your email object to your test. keep in mind all of your tests should work without dependency to other functionality or network issues or ...